# How to concatenate strings from random character with list?

Tags: python, list, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have this script that picks up random words from an URL and it concatenates with other special characters stored in a list:

```
import requests
import random
from random import randint
import string

url = 'https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain'
r = requests.get(url)

text = r.text
words = text.split()
random_num = randint(0, len(words))
random_num2 = [randint(0,10)]

special_list = ['#','!','@','-', '@']
union = "".join(str(x) for x in special_list)
special_char = random.choices(union, k=2)
special_char2 = random.choices(union)

final_string = (str(special_char).strip('[]') + words[random_num] + '__' + 
                str(random_num2).strip('[]') + str(special_char2).strip('[]'))
```

The output is something like that: `'-', '@'auxiliary__2'-'`.

The problem is even if I use `.join` I cannot get rid of `''` and concatenate everything together.

I also tried with:

```
   random_char = ''.join(string.punctuation for i in range(0,1))
```

instead using a special character list, but also this didn't work.

Comment: Ranges are exclusive so `range(0,1) == [0]`

Comment: Also, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choices` gives you a list. You can access things in the list like so: `special_char[0]` instead of converting the list to a string and messing about with the string. That way, you won't get the apostrophes that you get in the string representation of a list. `str(special_char)` ==> `['-', '@']` (for example). If you do `", ".join(special_char)`, you just get `-, @`. If you don't want the comma in between, just `"".join(special_char)` gives `-@`.

Also, `random_num2 = [randint(0,10)]` creates a list with just one number.
If you want to access just the number in the list, you need `random_num2[0]`.
Or you can convert them all to strings and use `",".join()` just like we did for `special_char`

```
random_num2_str = [str(num) for num in random_num2]
special_char = random.choices(union, k=2) 
special_char2 = random.choices(union)

final_string = ", ".join(special_char) + words[random_num] + '__' + ", ".join(random_num2_str) + special_char2[0]
```

Unless you really need `random_num2` as a list, you should do `random_num2 = randint(0,10)`. Then, you could do

```
final_string = ", ".join(special_char) + words[random_num] + '__' + str(random_num2) + special_char2[0]
```

Comment: thanks, it seems working. The reason behind random_num2 = [randint(0,10)] was that I just wanted one number. What is the difference between random_num2[0] ? It should return one number as well.

Comment: `randint(0,10)` returns one random integer between 0 and 10. You were putting it in a list before assigning the list to `random_num2`. To access the `x`th element of the list, you need to do `random_num2[x]`, or `random_num2[0]` because it only has the one element that you want to access.

Comment: alright, thanks, I understand now. By the way, I don't know why your answer was downvoted, I selected it as useful.

Comment: @Steven, you're welcome. You should upvote answers that you find helpful. Somebody has been downvoting all my answers today. No worries though, all the illegitimate downvotes will be removed at 3AM UTC today.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want the final output to be, but try:

```
random_num2 = [randint(0,10)][0]
```

then:

```
final_string = f"{''.join(map(str, special_char))}{words[random_num]}__{random_num2}{''.join(map(str, special_char2))}"
```

or you can get special characters by index:

```
final_string = f"{''.join(map(str, special_char))}{words[random_num]}__{random_num2}{special_char2[0]}"
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well!  is f{} a dictionary? If so I don't understand why it is used for this purpose.

Comment: No, it is an f-string.  A string format shortcut in Python 3. It allows you to directly inject variables, etc. into the string.  https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/